# How do I fill in a Word document received by email?

Tags: microsoft-word, documents, forms

I have received a form by email that has to be filled in and either printed or sent back by email. When I type, the characters move everything to the right like when you use the space key. Can't figure out why this is. What do I do to stop everything moving like that whenI type?

By the way, this is a Microsoft Word 97-2003 document

Answer (score 1):

Press [<kbd>Insert</kbd>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_key) to replace the existing text instead of moving it away.

[image]

Otherwise, print the document, fill it out by hand and scan it.

Comment: Does not work. It is a field that has to be filled in - like NAME......

Comment: Sorry, then I have a hard time imagining it. Would it be possible to get a screenshot of such a form? Or even an example document?

Answer (score 0):

The form was created with tab stops, go to menu bar, format then tabs from the tab pop-up window click clear all